# Selecting item from a list and converting to queue

Tags: c#, list

How to do to select items that have certain criteria and soon after convert to queue?

```
public class Assinante
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public string NossoNumero { get; set; }
        //public string Enviado { get; set; }
        public Status Pendente { get; set; }

        public Assinante(int id, string nome, string email, string cpf, string nossonumero, Status status)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Nome = nome;
            this.Email = email;
            this.CPF = cpf;
            this.NossoNumero = nossonumero;
            this.Pendente = status;
        }
    }

public static Queue<Assinante> CreatQueueList()
{
    return new Queue<Assinante>(assinantes.Where(x => 
        x.Pendente != Status.Sent || 
        x.Pendente != Status.NotFound && 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.NossoNumero)));
}
```

I have tried this way, however the return is still not as I wish ... it is returning objects that email is null

but I was looking for a more beautiful way to do this

```
Queue<Assinante> q = new Queue<Assinante>();
            foreach (var assinante in assinantes)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assinante.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(assinante.NossoNumero))
                {
                    q.Enqueue(assinante);
                }
            }

            return q;
```

Comment: It sounds pretty impossible that the object returning from the `CreatQueueList` [sic] method is null, you're using `return new`.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the definition of `Assinante` class.

Comment: Side note: if you're creating a `Queue<T>` only for having an access to "queue like processing", I would rather than creating a new object every time, create extension methods on `IEnumerable`

Comment: It's almost certainly a case of logical operator precedence. You'll need to first decide which order you want in the `CreateQueueList` method.

Comment: In your `CreateQueueList()`, there's a bunch of logical operators that look like this: `A || B && C && D`. In C#, `&&` evaluates before `||`. So your `B && C && D` will evaluate first, and then the result of that will `||` with `A`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a case of logical operator precedence.

In C#, the Logical AND (`&&`) takes precedence over Logical OR (`||`).

This should help you understand:

```
bool result = true || true && false;   // --> true 
bool result = (true || true) && false; // --> false
bool result = true || (true && false); // --> true
```

And in your example, you have a statement that's similar to:

`A || B && C && D`

`B && C && D` will evaluate first, and then the result of that will `||` with `A`.

So going back to your original,

```
x.Pendente != Status.Sent || 
x.Pendente != Status.NotFound && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.NossoNumero))
```

Essentially, you're picking;

- either objects whose `Status != Sent`,
  **OR**
- objets whose `Status != NotFound` **AND** `Email` is not null or empty **AND**  `NossoNumero` is not null or empty.

So, the first part allows object whose email is null to be selected in your `Where` clause.

---

### EDIT

Also, note that if you group `x.Pendente != Status.Sent || x.Pendente != Status.NotFound` together, that might be a problem too. `OR` operation on two `not`s doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The use of logical operators seems to be incorrect, you can try this revised query.

```
return new Queue<Assinante>(assinantes.Where(x => 
        !(x.Pendente = Status.Sent 
        || x.Pendente = Status.NotFound 
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email)
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.NossoNumero))));
```

If you look at the where clause, if any one option is true then entire condition will be false and that particular item won't be added to queue.